# Windows IAM without granting admin access

Tags: windows, user-management, local

I have an IAM team that needs to be able to create local administrator accounts but the customer doesn't want to grant that team Administrator access to the this team. Is there any way to create administrative users while restricting access to only that function?

Answer (score 0):

You can look into [Just Enough Administration](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/remoting/jea/overview?view=powershell-6), it allows normal users to perform specific administrative tasks. It needs some time to learn and set up, but it should solve your problem.